# Copy distinct values of one column to another table with different structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Using SQL Server, I have a table `RoleMembership`:

| Id | Username | RoleId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bobby | 1 |
| 2 | bobby | 2 |
| 3 | bobby | 3 |
| 4 | suzie | 3 |
| 5 | suzie | 4 |
| 6 | suzie | 5 |
| 7 | billy | 1 |
| 8 | billy | 7 |

etc.

I want to create a new `Usermember` table with a row for each distinct value for the  `RoleMembership.Username` column, alone with some ID and date columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [access].[Usermember]
(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

I want to copy the unique usernames such that the table will be as follows:

| Id | Username | CreatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bobby | 05-13-23 |
| 2 | suzie | 05-13-23 |
| 3 | billy | 05-13-23 |

How can I do an insert into select distinct to copy unique Usernames into a row in this new table?

I've tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO access.Usermember (Id, Username, CreatedAt)
    SELECT
        dbo.NextId('Usermember') + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id ASC), 
        (SELECT DISTINCT MemberName 
         FROM access.RoleMembership), GETDATE()
```

But the syntax isn't quite right.

Comment: [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL, how many users are you planning to have? INT should be enough for everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your table with an Identity column and provide a default value for `CreatedAt` then you simply have to worry about a single column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Usermember(
    Id bigint NOT NULL identity,
    Username varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    CreatedAt datetime2(3) NOT NULL default(Getdate())
);

insert into dbo.Usermember(Username)
select Username
from RoleMembership
group by Username
order by min(id); /* Assuming you wish to preserve the ordering, although this should not be necessary */
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use window function Find distinct and with row_number can generate new id

If you  don't  want(based on your business) the ID to be increased automatically, can use this row_number outside(this is code), otherwise it is better to be automatic.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Usermember (Id, Username, CreatedAt)
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id),Username,getDate()  from (
select   Username,id
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by Username  ORDER BY Username) rw
from  RoleMembership
)a
where a.rw=1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7vqonBNi)